# When does fetch() happen in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm having a problem with controlling the execution of my fetch() functions. Particularly I want to avoid letting the user spam fetch() requests.

My idea was to do this inside of middleware, but by the time the action with a fetch() gets there the payload is already a promise.

So my question is, when exactly does a fetch() already get executed?

If it matters, then my code looks roughly like this.

Parent action:

```
{
  return (dispatch) => {
    if (mode === 'MY') {
      dispatch(myAction(...);
    }

    dispatch(someOtherAction(...));
  } 
}
```

My action:

```
{
  type: 'TYPE',
  promise: post(url, payload)
}
```

My post method:

```
 {
   console.log('sending POST');

   return fetch(url, {
     //fetch info
   });
 }
```

My middleware:

```
{
  return next => action => {

    const { promise, //other fields } = action;
    //Already a promise here.

    if (!promise) {
      return next(action);
    }

    return promise.then(
      //Processing data
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: Reading through the Redux docs, I stumbled upon this line "...When an action creator returns a function, that function will get executed by the Redux Thunk middleware...".

Does this mean then that my issue is caused by Redux-Thunk? So that whenever my action is dispatched Redux-Thunk instantly executes my function way before it reaches my custom middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My idea was to do this inside of middleware, but by the time the action with a fetch() gets there the payload is already a promise.

To solve this problem, I would do it as a check inside the action. So when you fire the fetch request, dispatch an action that a fetch is currently executing, update the state to say `fetching = true`. Then in any other action that needs to use fetch, check against that state and return nothing if it's true.

To answer your comment:

When you call an action creator, that is called immediately of course. When you call the dispatch, that will then execute the function (if using redux-thunk). Now, since redux-thunk is a middleware, it executes depending on order that you attached the middleware. So if you put your own middleware in the setup before redux thunk, it will execute before it.

```
const store = createStore(
  combineReducers(reducers),
  applyMiddleware(yourMiddleware, ReduxThunk)
);
```

Otherwise you have the understanding correct. An action fires immediately after calling dispatch, it'll go through the middleware in order, and then pass the action info to your reducers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I tried changing the order of my middlewares and then logged what was coming into my custom middleware. I noticed that it was still receiving a promise.
If it goes through my middleware first before reaching Thunk, shouldn't it log my post method instead of a promise?

Comment: Whatever you pass to dispatch() and then to next() within middleware, is what middleware will receive. So if you want to call action.promise() then pass something else to the next middleware, you need to construct a new object and pass that to next(). redux-thunk doesn't do anything special with a function vs a promise. It just knows how to handle a function being returned instead of an object. It's crazy simple: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js